# Why my prediction result is very bad comparing with the accuracy

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

I write a code for image classification(2 categories, 'good'&'bad') in python using Keras, the accuracy on training data is about 99%, and on validation data is about 95%. (the image is 60 times 30 pixels grayscale png file)

```
img_width, img_height = 60, 30
nb_train_samples = 4000
nb_validation_samples = 600
epochs = 30
batch_size = 32

if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (1, img_width, img_height)
else:
    input_shape = (img_width, img_height, 1)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(16, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape,padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3),padding='same'))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))


model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))

model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['binary_accuracy'])

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale= 1. /255)
validation_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale= 1. /255)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    '/home/admin/Desktop/dataset/train',
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size=batch_size,
    class_mode='binary',
    color_mode='grayscale')

validation_generator = validation_datagen.flow_from_directory(
    '/home/admin/Desktop/dataset/validation',
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size= batch_size,
    class_mode='binary',
    color_mode='grayscale')

model.fit_generator(
    train_generator,
    steps_per_epoch=nb_train_samples // batch_size,
    epochs=epochs,
    validation_data=validation_generator,
    validation_steps=nb_validation_samples // batch_size)

model.save_weights('test_weights.h5')
```

now I want to make prediction for all the 600 images in validation directory, using this code.

```
path='/home/admin/Desktop/dataset/validation/good'
for file in os.listdir(path):
    im=cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,file))
    im=cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    im=np.reshape(im,[1, img_width,img_height,1])*(1. /255)
    result=model.predict_classes(im)
```

However, the result for 300 images in 'bad' directory is 9[1] with 291[0], and for 300 images in 'good' directory is 42[1] with 258[0], this is obviously wrong.

I think my way for data processing is different from **ImageDataGenerator** and **flow_from_directory**, which leads to the bug, but I'm not sure.

********update********

When I use the following code, the result is correct

```
predict_data=ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1. / 255).flow_from_directory(
    '/home/admin/Desktop/dataset/validation/good',
    target_size=(img_width, img_height),
    batch_size= 300,
    class_mode=None,
    color_mode='grayscale')

result=model.predict_generator(
    predict_data,
    steps=1)
```

But I still don't know where the bug is.

Comment: This is probably BGR (OpenCV) vs RGB channel ordering.

Comment: well, I use predict_generator to make the prediction and the results is correct, so I'm sure that the problem is the data processing.

Comment: the 3 channels for grayscale image should have the same value

Comment: Usually, good results in training with bad results in validation occurs due to **overfitting**. And I think that if the problem were different processing, the accuracy would be just terrible, not a significantly good number such as 95%. If you increase your dropouts, does it get better?